# Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Unexpected end of input

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

datamodel.prisma file

```
#SET_NULL (default) - CASCADE
 
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  posts: [Post!]! @relation(name: "PostToUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
  comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "CommentToUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type Post { 
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  body: String!
  published: Boolean!
  author: User! @relation(name: "PostToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "CommentToPost", onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type Comment {
  id: ID! @id
  text: String!
  author: User! @relation(name: "CommentToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  post: Post! @relation(name: "CommentToPost", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}
```

Showing error is

> ⚠ Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Unexpected end of input,
> expected OperationDefinition, FragmentDefinition or
> TypeSystemDefinition (line 1, column 1):
>
> ^: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax error while parsing
> GraphQL query. Unexpected end of input, expected OperationDefinition,
> FragmentDefinition or TypeSystemDefinition (line 1, column
> 1):\n\n^","requestId":"local:ckkmaj3l8001808560r4gxa51"}],"status":500},"request":{}}

can i solve this issue ?

prisma veriosn

> Prisma CLI version: prisma/1.34.0 (linux-x64) node-v14.4.0 Prisma
> server version: 1.34.10

Comment: Can you search for prisma logs with id `local:ckkmaj3l8001808560r4gxa51` and share them? And also, if you could share query which is returning this error, it will help. It is difficult to guess root cause just looking at datamodel.

Comment: after adding "prisma-binding": "^2.1.1" then solved this issue